# Making listings package print a \newpage mid-import

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I have a c++ source file that I am importing to Latex using the Listings package.
I found an obscure mention of using formfeed to create a newpage mid-import.

What I want to do:
Shift the comment relevant to the function rho() to the next page:
[image: Latex Output]

My attempt:
First I added formfeed to the listingStyle

[image: Defining formfeed in lstStyle]

I then added the following comment in my c++ source code (to get recognized as a formfeed):

[image: Formfeed in c++ source file]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % Use A4 paper by default, remove 'a4paper' for US letter

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, totalheight=\textheight, keepaspectratio} % Default images settings
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}} % Specifies where to look for included images (trailing slash required)
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\usepackage{units} % Non-stacked fractions and better unit spacing
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for better horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{listings}



\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.67,0.95}
\definecolor{codeorange}{rgb}{1,0.49,0}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.96}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codeorange},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    formfeed = \newpage,                  
    tabsize=2,
    xleftmargin=10pt,
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}


\title{3+1D Exercise}

\author{Rahul V. Silva}

\date{\today} % Date, use \date{} for no date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Print the title section

\lstinputlisting[language=C++, caption={C++ code for 3+1D exercise},label={lst:3+1D code}, mathescape=true, firstline=25]{3+1D code.cpp}

\end{document}
```

Imported code (3+1D code.cpp):
https://pastebin.com/T2J8q469

Output:

[image: Formfeed =\newpage not rendered]

Comment: Please add a compilable code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Done, added the latex code in a code block and the C++ code in a pastebin :)